# "Зеленый змий" — откуда пошло выражение?

Tags: фразеология

Пьянство аллегорично называют "зеленым змием". А откуда взялось это выражение? Это аллюзия к змию искусителю, или тут что-то другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зеленый змий - искушение алкоголем.

Выражение обязано своим происхождением традиционному русскому обозначению спиртного напитка -"зелено вино" (по цвету винограда, из которого оно изготавливалось). Прилагательное "зеленый" стало постепенно приобретать резко отрицательную оценку, так как пьянство, как известно, порок. Вспомним и о библейском змие-искусителе: на стыке значений двух этих выражений и появился фразеологизм "зеленый змий" - искушение алкоголем.

gramma.ru

Остаётся только добавить, что тут, пожалуй не совсем точно рассталевны акценты. Библейский змей за уши, имхо, притянут. Вернее всего это обычный для Руси образ змея, изначально не несший резко отрицательной оценки, скорее это символ неодолимой силы (сравните Змей Горыныч) и даже мудрости. И еще по некоторым предположением зло и зеленый вообще родственны.

Т.е. получаеется, что у Граммы препутаны причина и следствие. "Зеленый" равно "злой" изначально, а вот змей, напротив, приобрел эту окраску со временем. Тогда как по "Грамме" все получается наоборот.

Но это все частности. Никаких других сколько-нибудь убедительных "версий" я не знаю. История про галлюцинации - вторична, если не вообще за уши притянута, имхо. 
//----------
Да,еще забыл. "Зелено Вино" - никакого отношения к винограду не имеет. Вином на Руси называли любой спиртной напиток (креме медовых: меда, медка и медовухи) , в первую очередь - бражку

Answer (score 2):

Сперва почему зеленый. На Руси был термин "зелено вино". "Зелено" здесь значит не зелёное, а зельено, то есть сдобренное зельем, травами, хмелем, зверобоем и т. д., а не настоянная на меду. "Зелёный" для обозначения цвета, по Черных, стало использоваться лишь в XVI веке, когда термин за вином уже утвердился.

"Змий" (через и) по всей видимости от необходимого при производстве змеевика. Вкупе с явной отсылкой к библейскому сюжету, и сохранявшегося вплоть до XIX века горького привкуса, получилось очень образно, за счёт чего и сохранилось в народе.